# Adding a specific element to a map

Tags: react-native

I have a map fetched from database ..i want to add to every item in this array icon with different style ...This is my map in render..

```js
{
    this.state.categories.results.map((item, key) => (
        <View key={key}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
    ))
}
```

i want to add for each `item.name` a specific Fontawesome  icon so  i tried to put these icons with style in another map

```js
 const a = [
    {
        id: 1,
        icon: "car",
        style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: "#f56217" }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        icon: "home",
        style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: "#2c3e50" }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        icon: "tv",
        style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: "black" }
    },
]
```

than in render i added

```
<View>
    {
        a.map(i => (
            <FontAwesome name={i.icon} style={i.style} />
        ))
    }
    <View>
        {
            this.state.categories.results.map((item, key) => (
                <View key={key}>
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            ))
        }
    </View>
</View>
```

So there any way to add a specific element to this map without make a another map?
what is the most shortened way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define several type base on item.name for example :

```
const CATEGORIES_TYPES = {
  car: {
    style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: '#f56217' }
  },
  home: {
    style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: '#2c3e50' }
  },
  tv: {
    icon: 'tv',
    style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: 'black' }
  }
};
```

then in render :

```
this.state.categories.results.map((item, key) => (
    <View key={key}>
      {CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name] && (
        <FontAwesome name={item.icon} style={CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name].style} />
      )}

      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  ));
```